# is there a way inject one member to scala and not inject another member to the same class

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to create a class that injects a member but also takes a trait for another member which is set to a default.  The issues is the following code thinks both restService and siteInfoRepository are both being injected.

```
case class SiteInfoService @Inject()(restService: RestService)
(siteInfoRepository : SiteInfoRepository = new SiteInfoFileRepository) {...
```